# List index is out of range when comparing two elements in list

Tags: python

I think I have a blackout but I can't comprehend why I get a IndexError here.

```
    def gap(g, m, n):
        primes = list()
        
        for number in range(m, n + 1):
            if number % 2 != 0:
                primes.append(number)
                
        for i in range(len(primes) + 1):
            if primes[i + 1] - primes[i] == g:
                print([primes[i], primes[i + 1]])

gap(2,100,110)
```

Comment: `for i in range(len(primes) + 1)` -- maybe you wanted `- 1` rather than `+ 1`? Seems like nothing more than a typo that you were too tired to see.

Comment: I feel stupid now... Thanks for the help

Comment: For future reference, please try to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your code when problems like this come up. Test your assumptions; work backwards from the error message. In this case: first you determine what numerical index was tried when the `IndexError` occurred, vs. how long the sequence was. Then you check that the sequence length is what you expected, and that the index was computed in a way that makes sense. Then you work backwards out to the loop and check the loop bounds, etc.

Comment: No reason to feel stupid -- bugs are often easy to see after the fact but hard to see when you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with this line `for i in range(len(primes) + 1):` it should be `for i in range(len(primes) - 1):`

**You code should be like this:**

```py
def gap(g, m, n):
    primes = list()
    
    for number in range(m, n + 1):
        if number % 2 != 0:
            primes.append(number)
            
    for i in range(len(primes) - 1):
        if primes[i + 1] - primes[i] == g:
            print([primes[i], primes[i + 1]])

gap(2,100,110)
```

**Output:**

```
[101, 103]
[103, 105]
[105, 107]
[107, 109]
```

Comment: Thank you, I got it. Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: Welcome. Human error.. :D